# Minimise (optimise) particular eigenvalue in Python

Tags: python, matrix, optimization, eigenvalue

I have written a simple Python code that reads arrays from a file. All the array elements contain basic algebraic operations (e.g. `y*w+2*(w+y)`). These are read in, and then all the array elements are evaluated using the `eval` command (I know the security issues with using `eval`, but this script will only ever be used by me, and I hopefully won't do something stupid).

These arrays are then used to solve a general eigenvalue problem and eigenvalue and vectors are obtained. My question is how do I minimise (optimise) a particular eigenvalue by varying certain parameters within the matrix? Here is a basic example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import eig

y=10
w=3.45

x = np.array([[y+w,-2],[-2,w-2*(w+y)]])

eigenVal,eigenVec=eig(x)

print eigenVal[0]
```

The matrix is not the best example, but is just a minimal example. The idea is to vary the two parameters y and w to minimise a particular eigenvalue (e.g. the first eigenvalue, `eigenVal[0]`). I have written some basic optimisation algorithms in `C++` before, but wanted to explore the Python optimisaton library. These matrices can get very large, so what is the best way to go about this problem?

Comment: Look at this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import eig
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def my_func(x):
    y, w = x
    arr = np.array([[y+w,-2],[-2,w-2*(w+y)]])
    ev, ew=eig(arr)
    return ev[0]

x0 = np.array([10, 3.45])  # Initial guess

minimize(my_func, x0)
# ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
#       fun: -127806953.0230245
#  hess_inv: array([[1, 0],
#        [0, 1]])
#       jac: array([ 0.,  0.])
#   message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
#      nfev: 60
#       nit: 1
#      njev: 15
#    status: 0
#   success: True
#         x: array([-63809761.27752077, -63997191.74550374])
```

This `ComplexError` is worrying; you should use the `bounds` parameter or the `constraints` parameter. I don't know the constraints for your problem, so I'm skipping that part. A decent constraint would be that the matrix should be [totally positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_positive_matrix), which guarantees positive, *real* eigenvalues. But that's not possible, given that you have a constant `-2` in your matrix.

You can access the result of the optimization as:

```
a = minimize(my_func, x0)
print(a.x)
# array([-63809761.27752077, -63997191.74550374])
```